# Evaluate macro parameter only once

Tags: c, c89

I need to write a macro which traps any invalid index *i* for an array of length *n*. Here is what I got so far:

```
#define TRAP(i, n) (((unsigned int) (i) < (n))? (i): (abort(), 0))
```

The problem with this definition, however, is that the index expression *i* is evaluated twice; in the expression *a*[*TRAP*(*f*(), *n*)], for instance, *f* may have a side effect or take a long time to execute. I cannot introduce a temporary variable since the macro needs to expand to an expression. Also, defining *TRAP* as an ordinary function implies a run-time overhead and makes it harder for the compiler to optimize away the trap.

Is there a way to rewrite *TRAP* so that *i* is evaluated only once?

Edit: I'm using ANSI C89

Comment: You can make a function, which returns `i`.

Comment: *Why* do you need to make it a macro and not a function?

Comment: Never use a macro where a(n `inline`) function will do as well! Who told you there will be runtime-overhead for a function? That's nonsense if stated absolutely.

Comment: It's up to you as the programmer to avoid undefined behavior. If you wouldn't ever write something like `i = i++ + ++i;`, then you should also never write something like `MACRO(function_with_side_effects())`...

Comment: C89 is really an old and obsolete standard. Why can't you use at least C99 and preferably C11. Then you could define a `static inline` function in some common header, and use it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch C89 is not obsolete. It's supported by practically all current C compilers, something you can't say about C99: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99#Implementations. Moreover, to my mind C99 doesn't add anything really essential.

Comment: C99 adds `static inline` & flexible array members and you have two good free software compilers implementing it [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/). C11 has a better defined memory model. So yes, I believe you should upgrade your language standard and perhaps your compiler.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It's not just about "my compiler". For true portability C89 is still king.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom: That is your opinion, and some people (me included) disagree. C99 is much more "king" (if that has any meaning) than C89, and has more software written in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the macro *TRAP* when the index expression doesn't contain a function call and use a (non-macro) function *trap* when it does. This way the function call overhead only occurs in the rarer latter case.

Comment: With C99, if the function is declared `static inline` (or even if the function is small enough and its definition known to the compiler), most optimizing compilers would inline it and avoid the function call overhead. So in practice, always using a function is sensible.

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate once, and use the result, by doing something like this:

```
#define TRAP2(i, n) ({unsigned int _i = (i); _i < (n)? _i: (abort(), 0);})
```

This is a `gcc` specific solution, that will compile when used as the RHS of an assignment. It defines a (very) local variable, which might hide a prior definition of another variable, but that doesn't matter, as long as you don't try to use the prior version in the macro. But as people say, why do this in the first place?

Comment: This isn't the same as the original macro since the result isn't available. `unsigned int x = TRAP2(42, 102);` won't compile with your definition.

Comment: @PaulHankin -- good point, which really reinforces the "don't do it this way" argument!

Comment: This is well known to be an absolute **don't** macro. It will change the code structure for certain nested `if` statements.

Comment: I added braces `()` around the definition, to make it compile when used in assignments (see @PaulHankin's comment), but that is `gcc` specific I think. Again, this is a bad idea though...